# What's the behaviour when leaving out <DefaultProxy> element from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Looking through the documentation for [DefaultProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) element, I can seem to work out the behaviour if I leave out the section entirely. Will it try to use the default in IE or not use proxy altogether?

Comment: you should read **Remarks** : *If the defaultProxy element is empty, the proxy settings from Internet Explorer will be used. This behavior is different from version 1.1 of the .NET Framework.*

Comment: @V4Vendetta - an empty element is not necessarily the same as an element that does not appear at all - although it seems a reasonable assumption in this case, perhaps the OP is seeking confirmation of this.

Comment: Exactly, I was indeed seeking this confirmation